# Maple: How to rewrite $\sqrt{1-r^2\exp(2i\theta)}$ in Cartesian form

Tags: complex-analysis, maple

How can I rewrite $\sqrt{1-r^2\exp(2i\theta)}$ into Cartesian form using Maple. I could do it by hand but I need this type of simplification later for far more complicated expressions.

I allready tried to enter this as a complex number using $I$, but simplify(...,'symbolic') didn't simplify this expression. Any suggestion?

Comment: I apologize for my apparent incompetence, but is this not already the most simplified version of the expression? The only thing I can see you can perhaps do is to write it in trigonometric form, `convert(sqrt(1-r^2*exp(2*I*theta)),trig)` but calling this a simplification is questionable.

Comment: I need this for stability analysis. So simplification means express with real an imaginary part :)

Comment: Then it makes much more sense why you did not want to do it by hand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write your expression as $z = a + ib$, i.e. with a real and imaginary part you can use the functionals `Re` and `Im`.

```
z:=sqrt(1-r^2*exp(2*I*theta)); # Your expression

a:=evalc(Re(z));               # Real part
b:=evalc(Im(z));               # Imaginary part

z__1 := a + I*b;               # z expressed as a real and imaginary part
```

> $$z_1 := 1/2\,\sqrt {2\,\sqrt { \left( 1-{r}^{2}\cos \left( 2\,\theta \right) 
>  \right) ^{2}+{r}^{4} \left( \sin \left( 2\,\theta \right)  \right) ^{
> 2}}+2-2\,{r}^{2}\cos \left( 2\,\theta \right) }+i/2{\it csgn} \left( i
> \cos \left( 2\,\theta \right) {r}^{2}-{r}^{2}\sin \left( 2\,\theta
>  \right) -i \right) \sqrt {2\,\sqrt { \left( 1-{r}^{2}\cos \left( 2\,
> \theta \right)  \right) ^{2}+{r}^{4} \left( \sin \left( 2\,\theta
>  \right)  \right) ^{2}}-2+2\,{r}^{2}\cos \left( 2\,\theta \right) }
> $$

Comment: Thank you alot! That is exactly what I was looking for:).

Comment: @MrYouMath `a` and `b` can be simplified a bit with `simplify(a)` and `simplify(convert(b,exp))`. Just quickly trying, `convert/exp` seemed to help Maple get a nicer expression. Whether this is the best we can do, I have not checked, but at least it's much prettier than the output above!

Comment: Thank you, that will be very useful for my problem.